# System.Exception: Invalid license key at NReco.PdfRenderer.License while using the PdfToImageConverter.GenerateImage concurrently

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, nreco

I'm trying to use the [`PdfToImageConverter.GenerateImage`](https://www.nrecosite.com/doc/NReco.PdfRenderer/html/M_NReco_PdfRenderer_PdfToImageConverter_GenerateImage_1.htm) method concurrently, in various threads:

```
new PdfToImageConverter
{
    ScaleTo = this.settings.ScaleTo
}
.GenerateImage(
    pdfContentStream,
    task.Page,
    ImageFormat.Png,
    outputContentStream);
```

Usually, the method works fine, but sometimes it throws an exception:

```
System.Exception: Invalid license key
at NReco.PdfRenderer.License.a.B()
at NReco.PdfRenderer.PdfToImageConverter.b(A )
at NReco.PdfRenderer.PdfToImageConverter.A(A )
```

I set the license info once at the start of our service:

```
NReco.PdfRenderer.License.SetLicenseKey(
    "PDF_Renderer_Bin_Pack_....",            
    "Pc...30=");
```

Is the `PdfToImageConverter.GenerateImage` thread-safe, and how can I use the method in a multithreaded environment?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried calling `SetLicenseKey()` in each thread?  I don't imagine that's a particularly expensive call, given the heavy lifting this library does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been resolved in the latest version. We used outdated product version.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen when your license key initialization code (`SetLicenseKey` method call) is executed multiple times from several threads (in parallel). `PdfToImageConverter` can be used in multithread environment (each thread should use its own instance of the class).

`SetLicenseKey` should be executed only once (on the application start, from the 'main' thread); if this is not possible for some reason -- say, your service is Azure Function or AWS Lambda, you may use the following code snippet to guarantee a thread safety:

```
static object syncObj = new object();  // your class field

// code that initializes the license key
if ( NReco.PdfRenderer.License.GetLicenseKey()==null)
  lock (syncObj) {
    NReco.PdfRenderer.License.SetLicenseKey("owner_id", "key_value");
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.

I set the license key in Autofac module:
`
using Autofac;
public class NRecoModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        ...
        NReco.PdfRenderer.License.SetLicenseKey(
            owner,
            key);
    }
}
`

It is the only place where I call the `NReco.PdfRenderer.License.SetLicenseKey`.
I'll inspect the code for a concurrency, but I think the code is run only once - at the start of my service.

Comment: @SergeyVoronkov try to use a code snippet with `lock`, it should help in any way